# how to extract partial value from an element and assign as attribute to another element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-grouping

I am working on XML to XML transformations through XSLT.

I want to extract aprtial value from an element and assign that as attribute to new element.

Source XML:

```
      <content>
        <component>
      <aaa>HI
           <strong>[a_b_c]</strong>
              : More Information Needed
            <strong>[d_e_f]</strong>XXX
      </aaa>
     </component>
     <content>
```

Target XML:

```
    <ddd>hi<dv name='a_b_c'/>: More Information Needed <dv name='d_e_f'/> XXX

    </ddd>
```

can any one suggest how to do it through XSLT.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="aaa">
    <ddd>
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,'[')"/>
      <dv name="{substring-before(substring-after(.,'['),']')}"/>
    </ddd>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

or

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="aaa">
    <ddd>
      <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(.,'\[')[1]"/>
      <dv name="{tokenize(tokenize(.,'\[')[2],'\]')[1]}"/>
    </ddd>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**EDIT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="aaa">
    <ddd>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </ddd>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="content|component">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="strong">
    <dv name="{normalize-space(.)}"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion..I have edited the question can you just modify the answer like how to do it recursively.

Comment: @muzimil - I'm not sure what you mean by recursively. Your new input/output examples don't need string manipulation at all. You're just dropping the `content`, `component`, and `strong` elements and renaming the `aaa` element.

Comment: No am also dropping some part of the content..Like [a_b_c] etc. Recursively i mean that need to be done more than once(if more things need to be removed).

Comment: @muzimil - That content is in the `strong` element. Please try the stylesheet in my update.

Comment: sorry DevNull, i uploaded wrong question..Now i have edited the excat one, please have look at it.

Comment: @DevNull- Thank you very much..it really working very fine.It would be very helpful, if you can say how to avoid extra spaces that are there in source here.I also want to remove extra lines spaces present in the content.